# Video tab in programmable search engine

Tags: kotlin, search-engine, google-custom-search, search-engine-api

i am working on kind of custom search engine provided by the google. i applied taht link into android studio using kotlin with help of webView.
everything is fine, Result are show with two tab(web,image) but i wanted to add one more tab(Video) can we add video tab in programmable search engine

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about configuring Google Custom Search.